# How To append css attributes in <style> tag in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have an ajax web application, loading all parts in a single page such as index.html. Inner parts to be loaded in index.html exceeded 32 page(html, js, css).

Now I have trouble with CSS files to be include or `@import`. I thought I can merge all styles in  a style tag using JS at client side. The problem is, IE doesn't allow me to change the style tag in head of the page using JS.

Any suggestion?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dP29q/) is the fiddle of what I want to do in IE. It's working fine in other standard browsers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is right. It is really messy to put all of your styles in a style tag. Have one or a couple sheets where your styles are nicely organized and keep your code pages clean and maintainable. And minification is a good idea as well.

Comment: What these guys said! All web browsers can only have a limited amount of simultaneous requests to your site, this is also why you (ideally) should use a spritemap for your ui image files. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser

Comment: if it's any consolation, it does work in IE9 but not 6-8

Comment: It looks to me that you want to append the styles on the client side (in the browser) by using javascript. Is that the case?

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree: yes, exactly. The application is an ajax based and more than 32 pages are loading during some workflows. each page has its own html js and css file. is there anyway to combine them on client side using js?

Answer (score 1):

You can append new stylesheet to `<head>` instead:

```
$('head').append('<style >body {background:red;}</style >');
```

Or you can import styles together with remote pages, they do not have to be in `<head>` at all.

Comment: perfect! I didn't got the second solution. please explain more.

Comment: Simply, together with page you import/insert its styles. Once you remove page content, the styles are gone also. I assume you have an AJAX application and insert the pages on request.

Comment: You mean inline styles? If yes, I really do prefer the first solution.

Comment: No, not inline styles, just `<style type="text/css">...</style>` block can go together with page you insert, inside the `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

this is a stupid IE bug, well

try to use `@import url("extra.css") all;` inside of your css files

Comment: do not import the style-sheet.It decrease the speed

Comment: yepp, it decreases ^^ but if combining isn't an option, what else?

Comment: the you really need to combine

Comment: I think it's not the problem of server side. server side is serving css files on demand.

Comment: yes, it's really a thing of IE. the IEs only support 32 stylesheets -.-

Answer (score 0):

This works in IE 9 and Chrome 22:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style id="styleTag" type="text/css">
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function()
        {
            // append a stylesheet to the page's head (optional)
            var el = document.createElement("link"); 

            el.type = "text/css"; 
            el.rel = "stylesheet"; 

            document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0].appendChild(el);

            // get a reference to the newly added stylesheet
            var css = document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1];

            // OR get a reference to an existing stylesheet
            // var css = document.styleSheets[0];

            // add rules to the stylesheet
            css.insertRule("body {background:red;}", css.cssRules.length);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, world.</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

So you want to focus on referencing the style object, parsing your stylesheets' rules and adding them using `insertRule`.